# Remplazar cualquier contenido dentro de LLaves en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un script de python y tengo la siguiente función `retirar_llaves` lo que hace es lo siguiente: `Cadena = "Hola lo que este dentro de {estas llaves} será ignorado"` y sin importar lo que este dentro de las llaves sea eliminado del string: `{ignoraria esto} {esto}, {cualquier cosa dentro de las llaves}` y no se como hacerlo sin que sea usando `replace("{}")`, el problema es que el contenido de las llaves puede ser distinto, codigo:

````
    NuevaCadena = #que hago para remplazar cualquier contenido entre {}
    return NuevaCadena```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar regex.

El método `sub` se usa para reemplazar una coincidencia. En este ejemplo la coincidencia se reemplazará con un string vacío `""`

```py
import re 
Cadena= "Hola lo que este dentro de {estas llaves} será ignorado"
NuevaCadena= re.sub(r"{.*?} ?","", Cadena)

print(NuevaCadena)
# Hola lo que este dentro de será ignorado
```

- `.*`
  Coincide con cualquier carácter, seguido de cero o más caracteres.
- `?` Opcional: si encuentra un espacio o no después de `}` también coincide

Comment: una pregunta si pongo ? antes también coincide el espacio si es que hay uno antes?

Comment: Asi es, pones un espacio y la interrogación. Te quedaría asi `" ?{.*} ?"`

Answer (score 1):

A la fecha de esta respuesta, hay una solución que usa expresiones regulares y otra que solo sirve para cuando aparecen al menos y solo un grupo de llaves. Esta solución cubre n casos de llaves anidadas sin usar regex.

Nota: la siguiente solución no funcionará correctamente si se cierra una llave sin que se haya abierto una.

```
cadena = "esta es una {cadena {con llaves}} anidadas y {repetidas}"

# Esta función devuelve un objeto generador por el cual se puede iterar e irá devolviendo las letras que estén fuera de las llaves.
# Esta función hace casi todo el trabajo.
def _borrallaves_generator(cadena):
    # iniciamos con un nivel de llaves 0. O sea no se abrió ninguna llave.
    level = 0

    # iteramos sobre cada letra de la cadena
    for letra in cadena:
        # si la letra es igual a "{" aumentamos el nivel en 1.
        if(letra == "{"):
            level += 1
        # si no si la letra es igual a "}" disminuimos el nivel en 1.
        elif(letra == "}"):
            level -= 1
        # si no si el nivel es 0 (la letra no está entre llaves), se devuelve la letra
        elif(level == 0):
            yield letra

# Esta función tiene el unico proposito de unir en una sola cadena todas las letras devueltas por _borrallaves_generator
def borrallaves(cadena):
    return "".join(_borrallaves_generator(cadena))

print(borrallaves(cadena))
```

Produce:

```
esta es una  anidadas y
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo hay una pareja de llaves, se puede hacer algo como:

```
>>> Cadena = "Hola lo que este dentro de {estas llaves} será ignorado"
>>> Cadena.find("{")
27
>>> Cadena.find("}")
40
>>> Cadena[:28] + Cadena[40:]
'Hola lo que este dentro de {} será ignorado'
```

Entonces la solución sería:

```
>>> Cadena[:Cadena.find("{")+1] + Cadena[Cadena.find("}"):]
'Hola lo que este dentro de {} será ignorado'
```

Si son más llaves, o pudiera aparecer una `}` antes que `{`, entonces mejor usar la otra opción de expresiones regulares.